# reading line in output file that repeats but has different associated values

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python to open and read a file with a line that repeats in my output. The line is:

```
"AVE. CELL LNTHS[bohr]        =    0.4938371E+02   0.4938371E+02   0.4938371E+02"
```

the values change in each line ( with every step), but all lines start with AVE. CELL LNTHS[bohr]. I want to take the first of the three values from every line, and make a list.[the image is a snip of the output file and repeating line of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pCmy.png).

Comment: If `s` is the line of text: `[float(x) for x in s.split("=")[1].split()]`

Comment: I'm very new to python, and I'm still having trouble first finding all the lines that match : "AVE. CELL LNTHS[bohr]        =    0.4938371E+02   0.4938371E+02   0.4938371E+02", since the three values change

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `float` command to convert a string to number. Also, use `split` to split the line first on the '=' then on space. Lastly, use list comprehension to build a list from the parts of the string.

```
path_to_file = r"C:\Documents\whatever.csv"
with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("AVE. CELL LNTHS[bohr]"):
            values = [float(x) for x in line.split("=")[1].split()]
            # Do something with the values
            print(values)
```